# Excel Chart title will not accept a date concatonated to a string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

I'm trying to include a date in my excel chart title by putting a formula inside the title formula box:

="Some text "&TEXT(NOW(),"mmm dd")

I've tried putting the date into a cell, and referencing the cell, but that doesn't work:

="Some text "&TEXT(Statistik!$H$26,"mmm dd")

Strangely, I can put a date into the chart title:

=Statistik!$H$26

But as soon as I add text ("eg "&), it gives me an error message that there is something wrong in the formula. If I paste the same formula into a cell, it works fine. =Concatonate doesn't work either.

Comment: Put the whole formula into a cell, then just refer to that cell.

Comment: Indeed, this is the answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All credit to Rory. Put the whole formula into a cell, then just refer to that cell.

Concatenation within the title cell of the excel chart does not work. The title cell needs to be a single reference to another cell, eg, =A1, in which any concatenation occurs, eg, ="Some text "&TEXT(Statistik!$H$26,"mmm dd").